# Transfer elements from one list to another using for loop in Java

Tags: java, list, for-loop

Trying to transfer the elements of one string list to a temporary list using a for loop.

```
List<String> origin = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "var");
        List<String> temp = Arrays.asList();

        String a = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < origin.size(); i++) {
            //Want to format before adding to temp list
            a = doSomeFormatting(origin.get(i));
            temp.add(a);
        }
```

Keep getting an error: Exception in thread

```
"main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:153)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:111)
    at test/test.Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

Should this not be possible to do if for some case I want to run some formatting on the strings in the lists and transfer to a temporary list?

Comment: I suggest you check out the [Java Collections Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) in the official Oracle tutorials to learn more about how to properly use Lists as well as other data structures provide by the Java standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` returns you an immutable list, hence `UnsupportedOperationException` while adding. [Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) the javadoc and this is what it says:

> Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array. (Changes to
>   the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as
>   bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination
>   with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and
>   implements RandomAccess.

For your case, you can actually do it without any loop with the following line (i.e. by using constructor):

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList(origin);
```

**Update**

If you want to format then you can iterate and apply the format, e.g.:

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for(String element : origin) {
    String formattedElement = format(element);
    temp.add(formattedElement);
}
```

Here's Java 8 way:

```
List<String> temp = origin.stream()
    .map(e -> format(e))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I see, but the problem is that I want to be able to format each element in the original list before transferring it to the temp list.

Comment: @nemadT Note that you still need to create the `temp` list with `new ArraysList<>()` rather than `Array.asList()`.

Answer (score 2):

`Arrays.asList()` returns an immutable list. You should use some mutable list implementation instead, such as an `ArrayList`:

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList();
```